# Crossing over to new elements during touchmove

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I'd like to make it so that as you drag your finger over a set of elements, the background of the one you've got your finger on changes.

It seems like I want to use the touchmove event for this, but as far as I can tell the target element never changes, even as you drag around.  The clientX and clientY do change, and I found this `document.elementFromPoint` function that works in chrome, but seems very roundabout (plus I'm not sure which browsers support it)

See this fiddle, I want the boxes to turn green as you touch through them:

http://jsfiddle.net/QcQYa/9/

*By the way, in chrome, you'll need to go into the user agent tab of the inspector config modal and choose "emulate touch events" to see my example.*

**Edit:**
I found an idea to use `mouseenter` here [How to detect html elements on touchmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614711/how-to-detect-html-elements-on-touchmove?rq=1) and got it to work on desktop chrome, but not on mobile safari.

Comment: You have to look at the coordinates of your touchmove event and see if they overlap with the coordinates of your html element. I had to write that same code for a jquerymobile android game, I dont have it here at home but tomorrow can look it up and update your fiddle with it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I took a different approach:

Every touch event I check if the touch position is inside a `$('.catch')` object.

```
function highlightHoveredObject(x, y) {
    $('.catch').each(function() {
      // check if is inside boundaries
      if (!(
          x <= $(this).offset().left || x >= $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth() ||
          y <= $(this).offset().top  || y >= $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()
      )) {

        $('.catch').removeClass('green');
        $(this).addClass('green');
      }
    });
}
```

You can see it working on [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QcQYa/10/).
It works on Chrome, I hope it also does on mobile devices.

**Edit**:
In [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QcQYa/12/) I used both versions, mine and that one from the link in the comments ([document.elementFromPoint – a jQuery solution](http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/)), both seem to work on my Android phone. I also added a quick and dirty benchmark (see console) and as expected `document.elementFromPoint` is a few thousandth faster, if that is your concern you should check the support of `document.elementFromPoint` for the browsers you want to support.

Comment: seems to work, care to weigh in on this vs `document.elementFromPoint`?

Comment: Well certainly the browser incompatibility is the biggest drawback. I found 2 articles which might be in your very interest: [document.elementFromPoint – a jQuery solution](http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/) and [elementFromPoint() under iOS 5](http://www.icab.de/blog/2011/10/17/elementfrompoint-under-ios-5/). There you also see you have to calc the current viewport. I am not sure if the same applies to my solution. For me my solution looks less pain but it's up to you what to choose

Comment: What I didn't think of is that you need to address phone/tablet browsers. Unfortunately I don't know which mobile browsers support `document.elementFromPoint`. But I think if they all support them it would be a slight performance increase because internal functions happen to be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice. document.elementFromPoint works on iOS, but I'm going to use a modified version of your solution. After testing it out on my phone, it makes sense to allow the user's finger to drift slightly above or below the boxes as he slides left/right. The app store's ratings widget does this, for instance, and it makes it feel much nicer.  I can't handle that with `document.elementFromPoint`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find my solution in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QWyxZ/10/) , I tested it on my android phone and it works fine, it uses jquerymobile to take advantage of `vmousemove` event, it also attachs a handler to `touchmove` event just to prevent scrolling the browser view on the mobile device.

I paste here the relevant HTML and javascript bits:

```
<div id="main" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);">
   <span class='catch'>One</span>
   <span class='catch'>Two</span>
   <span class='catch'>Three</span>
   <span class='catch'>Four</span>
   <span class='catch'>Five</span>
   <span class='catch'>Six</span>
   <span class='catch'>Seven</span>
</div>
```

now the javascript:

```
function elem_overlap(jqo, left, top) {
   var d = jqo.offset();
   return top >= d.top && left >= d.left && left <= (d.left+jqo[0].offsetWidth)
          && top <= (d.top+jqo[0].offsetHeight);
}

/* To prevent WebView from scrolling on swipe, see http://goo.gl/DIZbm */
touchMove = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault(); //Prevent scrolling on this element
}

$("#main").bind("vmousemove", function(evt){
   $('.catch').each(function(index) {
      if ( elem_overlap($(this), evt.pageX, evt.pageY) ) {
         $('.catch').not('eq('+index+')').removeClass('green');
         if (!$(this).hasClass('green')) {
            $(this).addClass('green');
         }
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this different solution. I'm not using jquery mobile yet, but this seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "trigger a touchend event" or cancel touches, which you would need to start touching another.

So you would be better off binding the touchmove event to the container, and manipulating the boxes based on their position/sizes and the touch position, like what part of Dan Lee's answer does.