# How to add or modify my jquery for multiple selection to this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

### Issue

I want to be able to touch  my screen and drag my finger across the surface and select multiple boxes. I want to do the same thing with my mouse, where I hold down the mouse and drag it across whatever I want to select. Because of this, I am thinking that I would like to implement this in something like JQuery/JQuery mobile so that I have this behavior out of the box?

### Code

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/K8NGp1k66OzWW9atppKe?p=info) is my working sample of what I have working so far.

- Built a table and able to select specific  elements by color (and ignore another)
- Able to select by row or colum. Also able to unselect.
- Able to select entire table or unselect (by color).

### Attempts

I tried using JQuery UI. Specifically, the [JQuery selectable api](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid), but it breaks my existing code and is buggy. I also took a look at something I found here, but it is completely dependent on the desktop approach using shift and control. I also tried add select as an attribute to my `<td>` elements and use multiple select. I didn't think that hack would work, but I at least wanted to try it. Finally, looked at stackoverflow and it seems everyone wants to do this for checkboxes or with a keyboard.

Again, what I need is a way to be able to select multiple boxes/grids aka the  elements in my grid by touching screen and dragging it across whatever I wish to select or do the same with my mouse.

**Edit** This is a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013902/select-cells-on-a-table-by-dragging), it is similar but not what I need. Same use case, but applied to both mouse event + touch events.

Any suggestions, clues, hints, or more would be deeply appreciated as I have thrown everything and the kitchen sink at this. I feel like [this](http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/9b/92/ff/9b92ff11433b37ac214eab45caf11f40.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2014097/833188) with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397041/833188) and it seems to work both on desktop and on mobile (code is a bit ugly, sorry for that).

**How it works**

Every `<td>` on the table listens both to normal mouse events (up/down/move) and to touch events (start/end/move).

On `mousedown`/`touchstart` the motion becomes "active", selection is reset (removing `.highlight` class) and current event element is selected.

The trick is in the `touchmove` event: since `$(this)` always refers to the element where the touch event started, we have to see what the user is actually touching passing the event coordinates to `highlightHoveredObject`, which will select the right element.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5k1Lf88f/)**

**JavaScript**

```
function highlightHoveredObject(x, y) {
    $('td').each(function() {
      // check if is inside boundaries
      if (!(
          x <= $(this).offset().left || x >= $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth() ||
          y <= $(this).offset().top  || y >= $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()
      )) {

        $(this).addClass('highlight');
      }
    });
}

// if you are using jQuery Mobile replace the next line with
// $("#yourpage").on("pagecreate", function() {

$(document).ready(function() {  

    var active = false;

    $("td").on("mousedown", function(ev) {
        active = true;
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight"); // clear previous selection
        ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });

    $("td").on("mousemove", function(ev) {
        if (active) {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
        }
    });

    $(document).on("mouseup", function(ev) {
        active = false;
    });

    $("td").on("touchstart", function(ev) {
        active = true;
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight"); // clear previous selection
        ev.preventDefault(); // this prevents text selection from happening
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });

    $("td").on("touchmove", function(ev) {
        if (active) {
            var touch = ev.originalEvent.touches[0];
            highlightHoveredObject(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
        }
    });

    $(document).on("touchend", function(ev) {
        active = false;
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight { background-color:#ccffcc; }
```

Comment: It works for my mouse, but I am only getting one td element to select at a time with touch. In other words, no drag select with mobile.  Are you experiencing that?

Comment: JSFiddle works fine for me both on my Android device (Moto G) and on emulation in Chrome browser

Comment: I am on a Microsoft Surface and tested on IE explorer 11 (because of enterprise requirements). Let me check on Firefox. :-(

Comment: Okay, it works on firefox(yay!), but not IE11. What might be the reason for that? I gave you an upvote. :)

Comment: It's buggy on IE11, but it works. You have to hold your finger down much, much, longer. Thank you. If you don't mind, because I am a learner. Could you please edit your answer to include a basic summary of how this code works and the idea behind it? I am super humbled, but also want to learn how to be a better developer. I'll mark your contribution as the answer soon.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also try adding `-ms-touch-action: none;"` to your CSS?

Comment: I'll fork your code and do that shortly. I'll report back. Like this? See: https://jsfiddle.net/hf2008/5k1Lf88f/2/

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll research into what that is doing. Teaching me a lot today. If possible, could you please briefly explain what the boundary portion of the code is doing? The even listener stuff makes sense.  :D

Comment: Yes! thanks a lot, it is just what I was looking for.